# dired: read/write access to local folder contents (root/wheel), similar to "sudo -s"

Tags: dired, sudo

The local folder `/private/var/root` (owner: root / group: wheel) on OSX (El Capitan) contains certain data that I would like to have "read/write" access; e.g., `/private/var/root/Library/Caches`.  In the terminal, this can be done by typing the `sudo -s` command.  How can these folders/files be accessed (read/write) using `dired-mode`?

Comment: `C-x d /sudo::/private/var/root` ?

Comment: @phils -- yes, that resolves the issue.  I was looking for a way to pass along the "-s" command line option, but dired seems quite capable to handle this without manually adding that.  Thank you.

Comment: `sudo -s` (at least on my system) is for starting a shell, which isn't really relevant to dired.